# CSS3 - call back after animation done by adding class name

Tags: jquery, angularjs, css

How to make a call back in `angular` to call a function after completing animation adding a `className`?

here is my code :

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('count', function($scope) {
    $scope.animate = function () {
        $('h2').addClass('fade'); //adding animation 1s
        //opcity done how to put a call back?
        $scope.done = function () { //call after 1s..?
            console.log('done');
        }
    }
});

<div class="container" ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="content" ng-controller="count">
        <h1 ng-click="animate()">Click ME</h1>
        <h2>Let me Fade</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLgp1wzw/8/)

Comment: what I know is jquery cant catch the action happened in css .. so you cant check that by addClass

Comment: ok, can you show me the right way to do it? - updating my fiddle

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged jQuery, how about using this from jquery like `$(selector).fadeOut(speed,easing,callback)` where **speed** you can do "fast" or "slow" or define the milisec **easing** for speed increment whether it constant "linear" or faster at the end "swing" then the **callback function**, refer to this [article](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/eff_fadeout.asp)

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('count', function($scope) {
    $scope.animate = function () {
        $scope.done = function () { //call after 1s..?
            console.log('done');
        }
        $('h2').fadeOut("slow","linear", $scope.done)
    }
});
```

Here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLgp1wzw/9/) for you

EDIT:

Here is angularjs approach [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vLgp1wzw/13/) for you, but this isn't mine. I learned it [here](https://xyzhou.com/blogs/angularjs-with-animation-and-callback)

Comment: Yes I agree. works. But I guess this is not `angular` approach, since i mixing with `jquery`. stall for knowledge can you show me the `angular` approach here please?

Comment: @user2024080 updated my answer, but actually it kinda copy paste from what i learned back when i still use angularjs in my project. i miss angularjs so much

Comment: It seems your fiddle not work. Switched to other frameworks? - what is that? or left to other platform?

Comment: @user2024080 Hmmm strange, it does work. It is angularjs directive dont you know? Which one did you click? I modified yours lol